# How would I make Apache case insensitive using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, case-insensitive, capitalization

I recently switched from IIS to Apache and unfortionately some of my links have capitalization issues. I have seen quite a few people talking about how to rewrite urls to be all lowercase or all uppercase but I need something to just make Apache case insensitive. Is this doable with .htaccess?

Comment: Have you tried [this method](http://keystoneit.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/making-apache-case-insensitive/)? I don't think this can be done with `.htaccess`; this wouldn't fit the purpose of this file, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 14):

add

```
CheckSpelling on
```

to your `.htaccess` file
of course after enabling the RewriteEngine

so the final code will be

```
RewriteEngine on
CheckSpelling on
```

I guess it is the best and safest way.

## dont forget to change

```
AllowOverride none
```

## to

```
AllowOverride All
```

inside your `httpd.conf` file, to allow .htaccess files to work correctly.

Comment: I just get a 500 Internal Server Error on every page whenever I add `CheckSpelling on`

Comment: It is working like a charm for me.
try to remove everything else inside the .htaccess file other
than 
RewriteEngine On
CheckSpelling On

and make sure you AllowOverride All
inside you httpd.conf file

Comment: I've removed everything else. The only thing I haven't done is the httpd.conf file because I don't know how to access that. I'm on shared hosting with dreamhost. Is there a way to access that file, or do I have to find another way?

Comment: Well then, try to contact them and see if they allow using .htaccess or not and ask if they have the mod_rewrite loaded or not

Comment: They do allow .htaccess because I'm using it for other things. Thanks for replying.

Comment: For anyone else seeing this, you need the mod_speling module enabled as well.

Comment: For me it gave ' Invalid command 'CheckSpelling', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
'

Answer (score 1):

If `CheckSpelling` isn't working for you and you're using PHP, you can add a PHP redirect in your 404 page to redirect to the lowercase version of the URL. To start, if you haven't already done so, add the following code to your .htaccess file (you can call the file something else than 404.php if you want, but it has to be a PHP file):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then add the following code at the beginning of 404.php (if you're using HTTPS, change `http://` to `https://` at the second line):

```
if(preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){
    header("location:http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
    exit();
}
```

This code uses a simple regex to check if the requested URI contains uppercase letters, and if it does, it redirects to the same page but with lowercase letters.